# Firebase signinwithemail&password is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

I recently have been making a app for my IOS app and am introducing firebase email/password auth to my project.  The registration part works good but when i do the handleSignin function it doesnt quite work as expected.  Any ideas why

my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button,StyleSheet,View,Text, Image,SafeAreaView, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {auth} from "../firebase"
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth";
import { FirebaseError } from 'firebase/app';

export const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")
   const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("")
  const handleSignUp = (e) => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // ..
    });
  }
  const handleLogin  =  () => {
    auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(userCredentials => {
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      console.log('Logged in with:', user.email);
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error.message))
  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={styles.container}
    behavior="padding"
  >
    <Text style={styles.heading}>Unlock the power of time managment</Text>
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <TextInput
      value={email}
        placeholder="Email"
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
        secureTextEntry
      />
    </View>

    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={handleLogin}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
        onPress={handleSignUp}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText} >Register</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    width: '80%'
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "700"
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    width: '60%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#0782F9',
    width: '100%',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonOutline: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginTop: 5,
    borderColor: '#0782F9',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  buttonOutlineText: {
    color: '#0782F9',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

expo go error:
firebase.auth.signinwithemailandpassword not a function
firebase.auth.signinwithemailandpassword returned undefined

Answer (score 2):

Below is the guideline on what worked for me, you can try it.

Here is the explanation:
You have to import signInWithEmailAndPassword from firebase/auth.
Note: signInWithEmailAndPassword is a function that takes three arguments, ie auth, email and password.

```
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const signIn= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

   // for login 
   signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((auth) => {
    console.log(auth);
     if (auth) {
         // if successfully signed in, redirect the new user to the home page
      navigate('/');
    }
    }).catch(error => alert(error.message));

 };
```

Comment: Please, consider adding some explanation. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the new, modular SDK syntax, where most functionality is exposed as a top-level function, instead of as a method on an object. When you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` as a top-level function you pass in the `auth` object, and you need to do the same for signing in:

```
const handleLogin  =  () => {    
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  ...
```

I recommend keeping the Firebase documentation handy when troubleshooting problems like this, as the above is almost exactly the code shown in the <kbd>Web version 9 (modular)</kbd> tab in the section [signing in a user with an email address and password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password)

Comment: thank you so much!