# Firebase Authentication: "undefined is not a function" error when calling signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a React Native app that uses Firebase Authentication for signing in users. I have set up Firebase and imported it into my project, but when I try to call signInWithEmailAndPassword, I get an "undefined is not a function" error.

Here's the relevant code in my firebase.js file:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  config details
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export { auth };
```

And here's the relevant code in my SignIn.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import BackIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";
import FormError from "../components/FormError";
import { auth } from "../firebase/firebase";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

const SignIn = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [displayFormErr, setDisplayFormErr] = useState(false);

  function navigate(screen) {
    navigation.navigate(screen);
  }

  const validateInput = () => {
    let formInputs = [email, password];
    if (formInputs.includes("") || formInputs.includes(undefined)) {
      setDisplayFormErr(true);
      setErrorMessage("Please fill in all fields");
      return;
    }

    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {})
      .catch((err) => {
        setErrorMessage(err.message);
        return setDisplayFormErr(true);
      });
  };
// rest of comp
```

Comment: You are using legacy syntax with the modern SDK. Please have a read of the [upgrade documenation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) which walks you through it.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059165/firebase-signinwithemailpassword-is-not-a-function, which covers the same problem.